# Assigning pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have been working on this for a while and cannot seem to understand what is happening. I am trying to take the values in istr, put them in a linked list and sort them alphabetically. Eventually I will print them out. I am not sure where my problem is but I thought it was in the function InsertAfter. Is this not my problem and if so do you know what may be causing my linked list to not link? The last bit of code only outputs the headObj and not all of them, so I assumed that my list wasn't linking properly in nextNodePtr in each object but I am not sure. Thank you for your help!

```
void WordNode::InsertAfter(WordNode* nodeLoc) {
        WordNode* tmpNext = 0;

        tmpNext = this->nextNodePtr;    // Remember next
        this->nextNodePtr = nodeLoc;    // this -- node -- ?
        nodeLoc->nextNodePtr = tmpNext; // this -- node -- next
        return;
    }
```

wordNode.hpp

```
#ifndef wordNode_hpp
#define wordNode_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class WordNode {
public:
    WordNode(string wordval = "", int count = 0,  WordNode* nextLoc = 0);
    void InsertAfter(WordNode* nodePtr);
    WordNode* GetNext();
    void PrWordNodeData();
    string GetWord();
private:
    string word;
    WordNode* nextNodePtr;
    int wordCount;
};
```

wordNode.cpp

```
#include "wordNode.hpp"

// Constructor
WordNode::WordNode(string wordval,int count, WordNode* nextLoc) {
    this->word = wordval;
    this->wordCount = count;
    this->nextNodePtr = nextLoc;
    return;
}

/* Insert node after this node.
 * Before: this -- next
 * After:  this -- node -- next
 */

void WordNode::InsertAfter(WordNode* nodeLoc) {
    WordNode* tmpNext = 0;

    tmpNext = this->nextNodePtr;    // Remember next
    this->nextNodePtr = nodeLoc;    // this -- node -- ?
    nodeLoc->nextNodePtr = tmpNext; // this -- node -- next
    return;
}

// Print dataVal
void WordNode::PrWordNodeData() {
    cout << this->word <<": count=" <<this->wordCount << endl;
    return;
}

// Grab location pointed by nextNodePtr
WordNode* WordNode::GetNext() {
    return this->nextNodePtr;
}

//Returns word
string WordNode::GetWord()
{
    return word;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "wordNode.hpp"

int main() {
    WordNode* headObj  = 0; // Create WordNode objects
    WordNode* currObj = 0;
    WordNode* nextObj = 0;

    string istr ="555 999 777 333 111";
    istringstream instring(istr);
    string temp;

    //Assigns first word to the head object
    if (!instring.eof()){
        instring >> temp;
        headObj=new WordNode(temp,1);
    }


    currObj=headObj;
    while (!instring.eof()){
        instring >> temp;
        nextObj=new WordNode(temp,1);

        //swaps values if currObj is greater than the next word
        if(currObj > nextObj) {
        currObj->InsertAfter(nextObj);
        }
        currObj=nextObj;
    }



    // Print linked list
    currObj = headObj;
    while (currObj != 0) {
        currObj->PrWordNodeData();
        currObj = currObj->GetNext();
    }
    string i;
    cin >> i;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ` nodeLoc's pointer won't assign to tmpNext` -- What do you mean it won't assign? What exactly happens?

Comment: "but nodeLoc's pointer won't assign to tmpNext" -- and you reached this conclusion because ...? I'm confident that assignment statement works perfectly fine.

Comment: Is it a runtime issue to a compiler error?

Comment: "swaps values if currObj is greater than the next word" -- and what do you intend to accomplish by comparing raw pointer memory addresses?  P.S. If this meaningless pointer comparison goes the wrong way, your link list is going to be utterly broken, because you fail to link the new node with the existing list, which is likely to be your real bug, here.

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I should reword my question. I am trying to take the values in istr, put them in a linked list and sort them alphabetically. Eventually I will print them out. I am not sure where my problem is but I thought it was in the function InsertAfter. Is this not my problem and if so do you know what may be causing my linked list to not link? The last bit of code only outputs the headObj and not all of them, so I assumed that my list wasn't linking properly in nextNodePtr in each object.

Comment: As Sam pointed out, if I were you I would look at `if(currObj > nextObj)` and see if that makes sense.

Comment: I understand that is illogical. I added a new function, GetWord() which returns the word and changed my if statement to: if(currObj->GetWord() > nextObj->GetWord()). Is this the correct fix? I am still running in to the same issue.

Comment: In `InsertAfter(...)` you are saying `nodeLoc->nextNodePtr = tmpNext;`. Maybe I have been too wrapped up in the way Java handles objects, but since `nextNodePtr` is a private member, I do not think can directly set it. Perhaps you can in C++ because you are already in the class (*even though you are not in `nodeLoc`'s instance of the class*); however, I am just thinking about this from a somewhat Java-like point of view.

Comment: In the very first iteration of the loop you loose the reference to the head object and hence subsequent iterations will add nodes to a list that is not linked with the head. You gotta review your logic, in the sense that if you cannot "InsertAfter" because is higher alphabetically then you gotta "InsertBefore", just to give an example.

Comment: @SpencerDoak 'private' in C++ means private to the class. It means the same in Java too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the very first iteration of the loop (using the string you gave as example) you loose the reference to the head object and hence subsequent iterations will add nodes to a "headless list".

```
currObj=headObj;
while (!instring.eof()){
    instring >> temp;
    nextObj = new WordNode(temp,1);

    //swaps values if currObj is greater than the next word
    if(currObj->GetWord() > nextObj->GetWord()) {
        currObj->InsertAfter(nextObj);
    }
    // And what happens if it is not greater?
    currObj = nextObj; // Loose reference to head here if not greater
}
```

To fix your code you will either just have to add all nodes to the list and then sort it with a [sorting algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19169324/5583153) or insert them on the fly as you intend to do now. However, to do the latter you will have to modify your insertion logic, i.e. insert node at the beginning (if new node is alphabetically lower than the first element) or at the end. I recommend reading [this nice article about **singly linked lists**](http://codingfreak.blogspot.com/2009/08/implementation-of-singly-linked-list-in.html). It has examples and code for the insertions mentioned.